# Best method for comparing XML folder data

Tags: xml, vb.net

We are migrating server environments from one network to another. The networks are completely separated and cannot see each other. I am writing a program that will compare the files on our current production file server with the files on our future production file server.

The program needs to list the following:

- Files missing in future server from current production server
- Files that are out of date in the future server from our production server

The quickest way I could think of was to create a program that would browse through each folder and create an object to hold all files and folders. I then took that structure and serialize it into XML format. The end result is that I would have two files containing all files and folders on each server.

My problem now is that I need an easy way to compare the two files to see any discrepancies. The method that I thought of would be to deserialize the current production XML file back to the objects, and loop through each file/folder checking to see if the files exist on the future production server.

Besides manually looping through each file, is there an easier way to compare the two XML files to see which objects are different?

Here is the code I am using to generate the two files:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        Dim objFolder As New Folder
        objFolder = GetFolder("FOLDER TO BROWSE")

        Dim strObjects As String = SerializeObject(objFolder)
        With New StreamWriter("Out Path")
            .Write(strObjects)
        End With

    End Sub


    Function GetFolder(ByVal strPath As String) As Folder
        Dim objFolder As New Folder
        For Each File In New DirectoryInfo(strPath).GetFiles
            Dim oFile As New File
            oFile.Name = File.Name
            oFile.FullName = File.FullName
            oFile.DateCreated = File.CreationTime
            oFile.DateModified = File.LastWriteTime
            objFolder.lstFiles.Add(oFile)
        Next

        For Each Folder In New DirectoryInfo(strPath).GetDirectories
            objFolder.lstFolders.Add(GetFolder(Folder.FullName))
        Next

        Return objFolder
    End Function

    Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal objToSerialize As Object) As String
        Dim objXML As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType) 
        Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter() 
        objXML.Serialize(sw, objToSerialize) 
        Return sw.ToString() 
    End Function

    Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(ByVal strSerializedObject As String, ByVal objType As Type) As Object
        Dim objXML As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objType) 
        Dim sr As New IO.StringReader(strSerializedObject)
        Return CType(objXML.Deserialize(sr), Object) 
    End Function

End Class

<Serializable(), Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(File))> _
Public Class Folder
    Public lstFiles As New List(Of File)
    Public lstFolders As New List(Of Folder)
End Class

<Serializable()> _
Public Class File
    Public Name As String
    Public FullName As String
    Public DateCreated As String
    Public DateModified As String
End Class
```

Comment: If you expect there to be few differences and can arrange for the XML files to have the data in the same order (except for differences) you could use the [fc command](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/fc.mspx?mfr=true). Also, what are the chances of the filetimes actually being the same when they should be the same?

Comment: I would dump the results to 2 different tables in a database and write sql queries to find all the differences. Other than that, you are only left with file compare tools like Beyond Compare to help you.

Comment: Why don't you simply use some kind of vpn software that should make it simple to compair the directory listenings which some common tools which are freely aviable? By the way you don't need to favoriet your own question. You will be informed for every comment or ansswer automatically.

Comment: @rekire That would probably be an option for smaller companies, but not at the place I work. The transition is part of a merger between acquired business units which have separate servers on an isolated network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using the method I described above. I simply deserialized the object and looped through each file, checking if the target file exists and comparing other data points.

Here is the code:

```
Imports System.IO 

Public Class Form1 

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load 
        Dim objFolder As New Folder 
        Dim strObjects As String = "" 

        With New StreamReader("INPUT FILE PATH") 
            strObjects = .ReadToEnd 
        End With 

        objFolder = DeserializeObject(strObjects, GetType(Folder)) 
        CheckFiles(objFolder) 

    End Sub 

    Sub CheckFiles(ByVal oFolder As Folder) 
        Dim FileName As String = "OUTPUT FILE PATH" 
        Dim strWrite As String = "" 
        For Each oFile In oFolder.lstFiles 
            If System.IO.File.Exists(oFile.FullName) Then 
                Dim fi As New FileInfo(oFile.FullName) 
                If fi.LastWriteTime <> oFile.DateModified Then 
                    strWrite += vbCrLf & oFile.Name & "," & oFile.FullName & ",File Out of Date," & oFile.DateModified 
                End If 
            Else 
                strWrite += vbCrLf & oFile.Name & "," & oFile.FullName & ",File Does Not Exist," & oFile.DateModified 
            End If 
        Next 
        Dim sw As New StreamWriter(FileName, True) 
        sw.Write(strWrite) 
        sw.Close() 
        sw.Dispose() 

        For Each oFolder2 In oFolder.lstFolders 
            CheckFiles(oFolder2) 
        Next 
    End Sub 

    Public Shared Function SerializeObject(ByVal objToSerialize As Object) As String 
        Dim objXML As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objToSerialize.GetType) 
        Dim sw As New IO.StringWriter()
        objXML.Serialize(sw, objToSerialize)
        Return sw.ToString() 
    End Function 

    Public Shared Function DeserializeObject(ByVal strSerializedObject As String, ByVal objType As Type) As Object 
        Dim objXML As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(objType)
        Dim sr As New IO.StringReader(strSerializedObject) 
        Return CType(objXML.Deserialize(sr), Object) 
    End Function 

End Class 

<Serializable(), Xml.Serialization.XmlInclude(GetType(File))> _ 
Public Class Folder 
    Public lstFiles As New List(Of File) 
    Public lstFolders As New List(Of Folder) 
End Class 

<Serializable()> _ 
Public Class File 
    Public Name As String 
    Public FullName As String 
    Public DateCreated As String 
    Public DateModified As String 
End Class
```